# Embed aac (m4a) file into HTML

Tags: javascript, html, quicktime

I'm searching for the best up-to-date way to embed a m4a file into HTML. I want the standard controls to hide and replace them with my own controls. The control of the volume through JavaScript for fade in and fade out and the detection if the QuickTime plugin is installed is also important.

Is there any JavaScript library that can do this? I was looking at apple.com, and they are using an html tag called 'audio-preview-url', but I couldn't figure out, how they embed the quicktime plugin for playing that preview url.

Another

thx,
tux

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved it by myself: I'm now using the AC_QuickTime.js from quicktime to embed the code. If anybody doesn't know, there is a strange behaviour of the plugin, when you are trying to hide the timeline itself: You can only control the plugin through javascript, when the timeline is visible in your HTML file. I don't know why, if anybody has a solution, feel free to tell me ;)